# selecting specific cells in a structure array based on the values of the field

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

Data looks more like this:

```
DATA = struct('Direction',{[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,1,2],[2,2,2,2]},'Tr‌ial'{'correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct','correct'});
```

**this is just an example and i have other fields as well**

So for example, I just want to work with the cells in my `struct` which have the Trial as `correct`, so I want to select those cells and I would like to store those cells in a separate `struct`. I am not sure if I'm clear or not I apologize for that.

Same for if I want to select only those cells which the direction field that is a vector as what I have here with different sizes but I want to select only those vectors that all their elements are "2" only.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can filter only the elements with `Trial` = `'Correct'` like this:

```
DATA = DATA(arrayfun(@(x) strcmp(x.Trial, 'correct'), DATA))
```

If you also want to filter only the elements where `Direction` = `2` (all values), then also do this:

```
DATA = DATA(arrayfun(@(x) all(x.Direction == 2), DATA))
```

Or you can do all above in just one line like this:

```
DATA = DATA(arrayfun(@(x) strcmp(x.Trial, 'correct') & all(x.Direction == 2), DATA))
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much
do you know how I can retrieve it or if I can save them initially in a new struct? thanks so much

Comment: Sure! Just use a new name when assigning the value. Instead of `DATA = DATA(...)`, use `DATA2 = DATA(...)` or whatever name you want. :)

Comment: For the first part you can avoid `arrayfun`: `DATA = DATA(strcmp({DATA.Trial},'correct'))`